# Как добавить с помощью jQuery скрытое поле в форму

Tags: jquery

Задача сделать защиту от спам-ботов по примеру - [ссылка](http://www.blogovoe.ru/blog/prostaya_idealnaya_zashita_form_ot_spambotov.html)

Код формы

```js
var inp = ' input type="display" name="ncapt" value="< ?echo md5(date('Y-m-d').'www.law-jus.ru');? >" '; 

$("#form").append(inp);
```

```html
<form id="form" class="blocks" action="" method="post">
  <p>
    <p class="title-formi">
      <!-- <?php echo $module->title;?> -->
    </p>

    <p>
      <p class="ext-callback-field-name">
        <input required type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo $ext_attribute_name; ?>" pattern="^[А-Яа-яЁё\s]+$" />
      </p>
      <p class="ext-callback-field-phone">
        <input required type="text" class="text" name="phone" placeholder="<?php echo $ext_attribute_phone; ?>" />
        <!-- <?php if ($ext_show_message > 0) { ?> -->
        <p class="ext-callback-field-message">
          <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="<?php echo $ext_attribute_message; ?>" required></textarea>
        </p>
        <!-- <?php } ?> -->
      </p>
      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="<?php echo $ext_send_label;?>" name="extsendcallback" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите добавить инпут в форму, при этом значение инпута будет передано при помощи PHP, то код JS будет выглядеть вот так:

```
<script>
    let nospam = '<input type="hidden" name="ncapt" value="<? echo md5(date("Y-m-d")."www.law-jus.ru"); ?>">';
    $('form').append(nospam);
</script>
```

Comment: CbIPoK2513, спасибо за ответ. Скрытое поле появилось. Не подскажете как сделать проверку на php этого поля? У меня такой код проверки [                                                                                                  
   if (!empty($_REQUEST["ncapt"]) && $_REQUEST["ncapt"] == md5(date("Y-m-d").'www.law-jus.ru')) {
//ok
}
else {
//error
} ]                                                                                                                                                        
  Этот код не проверяет форму. Форма обрабатывается как обычно.

Comment: @ДенисЖуков, впервые слышу о `$_REQUEST`, посмотрите через какой запрос уходят данные, если через GET, то тогда `If(!$_GET["ncapt"] && $_GET["ncapt"] == md5(date("Y-m-d")."www.law-jus.ru")) {//true} else {//false}`

Comment: Данные через POST уходят. Код вставил такой же, как в моем предыдущем комментарии с $_REQUEST . Код рабочий. Проверил его вручную, выставив input в display. Добавлял в поле символы, буквы, цифры. И самое главное ни один бот пока не отправил почту. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: if (!empty($_REQUEST["ncapt"]) && $_REQUEST["ncapt"] == md5(date("Y-m-d").'www.law-jus.ru')) {  код обработчика }